# How to close all broswers except quality center in QTP?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

[image]

I have below code but sometimes it gets an error as object not visible.

```
Dim TempIndex,oDesc
'1) Create a Browser object'
Set oDesc=Description.Create
oDesc("micclass").Value="Browser"
TempIndex=0

'2) loop and Check if a browser is open'
While Browser("micclass:=Browser","index:="&TempIndex).exist(0) and TempIndex<Desktop.ChildObjects(oDesc).count
'3) Close the browser if its not Quality center '
        If instr(1, Browser("micclass:=Browser","index:="&TempIndex).getRoProperty("name"),"HP Application Lifecycle Management 12.50") = 0 Then
        Browser("micclass:=Browser","index:="&TempIndex).close
        else
        TempIndex=TempIndex+1
        End if
Wend
```

Comment: Check my [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32056517/1652222) for same question.

Comment: Thanks but I already tried after seeing that post before, but it did not work for me.

Comment: What do you mean it did not work? Have you installed ALM Explorer?

Comment: Sorry Sir, I understood in wrong way, It helped my issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a old thread but maybe my response be useful for anymore.
I had the same trouble. The solution was clean the objects in the final of script. Add this in the final:

Set oDesc = Nothing

Set TempIndex = Nothing

Goodluck,